# Automatically trigger Syntax Validation in TextMate PHP Bundle

Tags: php, textmate

I love text mate, but sometimes I do miss some IDE features.

One of which is the ability to automatically check syntax as you type or after you hit enter or the arrow keys etc to leave a line.

in textmate's PHP Bundle you can check the syntax using the Control-Shift-V keyboard shortcut.  Which is great, but That requires user input.  I know some may say lazy, but I just like to maximize my coding speed and not have to stop to run checks.

is there a way to get this command to auto trigger on either Returns or leaving the current line?  right now the syntax error shows up as a tootlip, could this be changed to display an error type on the line?  (error as in the syntax color theme type).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

To have the Validate Syntax command execute with each return you could record a macro. While recording, execute the validate syntax command and press return. Save your macro and give it a key equivalent of the return key. Now when you press return it's going to override the default behavior of simply inserting a return and instead run the command and then insert the return. Since you probably don't want this to always happen (for example, if you're editing non-PHP files) set the scope of the macro to `source.php`.

[image: Override Return Character]

To have the error appear within the file instead of within a tooltip, you're going to need to either edit the existing Validate Syntax command or duplicate it and use the duplicate instead, with the output set to Insert as Text instead of Show as Tool Tip.

Comment: BRILLIANT! that does exactly what I need it to!  btw turns out the tool tip is good enough because it automatically sends your cursor to the line for the first error.  though what I ended up doing is doing this in reverse, insert the new line first and then execute the syntax check because otherwise the cursor jumps to the error and then enters a new line.

Comment: This is a great idea in theory. However, it doesn't work in practice. E.g. if you type `if ($something = 1) {` and then hit the enter key, the validate action will think that the file is not valid. And it won't create a new line. When it should let you create the new line, so you can then type `}` to complete the if statement.